# Setup Virtual host in home directory - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apache2, php

This is an extension to the following question  :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/617190/how-to-setup-apache2-virtualhosts-on-your-home-directory-on-ubuntu-14-04

---

I'm trying to setup a virtual host to run apps from my home directory

> /home/byteseeker/projects/blogapp

I followed all the steps listed by the user @Vinicius Santana and also included the correction answered by @Doug Smythies in the above mentioned question.

The Virtual Host file in

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/blogapp.conf

looks like this

> < VirtualHost *:80 >
>
> > ServerAdmin webmaster@blogapp.dev
> >     ServerName blogapp.dev
> >     ServerAlias www.blogapp.dev
> >     DocumentRoot /home/byteseeker/projects/blogapp/
> >     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
> >     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
>
> < /VirtualHost >

And the < Directory > tag in

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

(as pointed out in referred question's solution ) looks like this

> < Directory / >
>
> > Options FollowSymLinks
> >     AllowOverride None
> >     Require all denied
> >     < /Directory >
>
> < Directory /usr/share >
>
> > AllowOverride None
> >     Require all granted
>
> < /Directory >
>
> < Directory /var/www/ >
>
> > Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> >     AllowOverride None
> >     Require all granted
> >     < /Directory >
>
> < Directory /home/byteseeker/projects/blogapp/ >
>
> > Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> >     AllowOverride None
> >     Require all granted
> >     < /Directory >

The Hosts file in

> /etc/hosts

has the contents as

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>   127.0.0.1 anonymous
>   127.0.0.1 blogapp.dev

I have also put a "index.html" file in

> /home/byteseeker/projects/blogapp

with a simple welcome message

Now when I try to go to blogapp.dev , I always end up getting the same "It Works" page that I get when accessing "localhost"

What's possibly wrong with my setup ?

N.B: 
I'm using

> > 1. Apache 2.4.12
> > 2. PHP 5.6.11
> > 3. Ubuntu Mate 15.10

Comment: You have not enabled your new virtual host. Try `sudo a2ensite blogapp.conf` and then `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Comment: IMHO this is not the best of ideas - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www and http://kimbriggs.com/computers/computer-notes/linux-notes/apache2-public_html-virtual-directories.file

Comment: @fkraiem I have enabled my virtual host and restarted apache2 . Din't solve my problem

Comment: to avoid caching issues, run "curl blogapp.dev". If this still returns "It Works", disable the original config file with `sudo a2dissite 000-default` and try again.